# Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.twitter.com:443

Tags: r, ssl

I am getting an error when trying to authenticate using Twitter API in R.

Result of `cred$handshake(cainfo = system.file("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl")`)
is '*Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.twitter.com:443*'

Expected result: It should ask for pin generation in twitter app but instead it is displaying error.

Comment: Was this solved?

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar problem which I posted here

[Errors when trying to stream from the Twitter API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58190121/errors-when-trying-to-stream-from-the-twitter-api)

The solution was to update R

```
# installing/loading the latest installr package:
install.packages("installr") 
library(installr) # install+load installr
updateR() # updating R.
```

and re-install the packages that I used for the Twitter API (TwitteR, streamR)