# Errors when trying to stream from the Twitter API

Tags: r, twitter, streaming, twitter-oauth, devtools

I am trying to stream data from Twitter, by using StreamR and this guide https://github.com/pablobarbera/streamR

It worked recently, but now I get this error when I try to stream any data;

```
library(ROAuth)
library(streamR)

my_oauth <- list(consumer_key = "...",
   consumer_secret = "...",
   access_token="...",
   access_token_secret = "...")

getUsers(screen_names="LSEnews", oauth = my_oauth)

#Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE)  : 
  #Unknown SSL protocol error in connection to api.twitter.com:443

When I try to stream tweets the connection closes after 0 second

filterStream(file.name="trump-tweets.json", track="trump", timeout=120, oauth=my_oauth)
#Capturing tweets...
#Connection to Twitter stream was closed after 0 seconds with up to 0 tweets #downloaded.
```

I have re-generated my costumerkeys and access tokens on the Twitter developer site and also created a new app. I have also tried to update the ROAuth and streamR -package. However, when I try to update streamR from github, I get this error (I have installed the package before without any problems);

```
library(devtools)

#Loading required package: usethis
devtools::install_github("pablobarbera/streamR/streamR")

#Error in rethrow_call(c_processx_exec, command, c(command, args), stdin,  : 
#  Incorrect number of arguments (16), expecting 14 for 'processx_exec'
```

Which led me to this answer that I might need to update the processx package

https://github.com/r-lib/devtools/issues/2077

Which I have updated by

```
install.packages("processx")
```

But it did not solve the problem, I still get the same error when I try to update the StreamR package from Github. I have also tried to install the streamR-package through CRAN;

```
install.packages("streamR")
install.packages("ROAuth")
```

But it did not solve my primary problem about streaming tweets.

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: short answer: use the package `rtweet` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to successfully run the code as per below (proving that it is indeed an issue with your setup and nothing has changed in the API or package itself).

A couple notes:

- I installed the github version of streamR
- Notice that I couldn't run the function `getUsers`; I suspect that function is from the CRAN version
- I've included the output of `sessionInfo()`; perhaps if you ensure you have the same package versions and R version as I do you will be able to run successfully or at least lead you in the direction

```r
library(streamR)
#> Loading required package: RCurl
#> Loading required package: bitops
#> Loading required package: rjson
#> Loading required package: ndjson

my_oauth <- list(consumer_key = "MY_CONSUMER_KEY_HERE",
                 consumer_secret = "MY_CONSUMER_SECRET_HERE",
                 access_token="MY_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE",
                 access_token_secret = "MY_ACCESS_SECRET_HERE")

filterStream("tweets.json", track = c("Obama", "Biden"), timeout = 120, 
             oauth = my_oauth)
#> Capturing tweets...
#> Connection to Twitter stream was closed after 120 seconds with up to 1146 tweets downloaded.

getUsers(screen_names="LSEnews", oauth = my_oauth) #not a function I see
#> Error in getUsers(screen_names = "LSEnews", oauth = my_oauth): could not find function "getUsers"

# List all functions in this package
ls("package:streamR")
#> [1] "createOAuthToken" "filterStream"     "parseTweets"     
#> [4] "readTweets"       "sampleStream"     "userStream"

filterStream(file.name="trump-tweets.json", track="trump", timeout=120, oauth=my_oauth)
#> Capturing tweets...
#> Connection to Twitter stream was closed after 120 seconds with up to 5187 tweets downloaded.

sessionInfo()
#> R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
#> Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
#> Running under: macOS Catalina 10.15
#> 
#> Matrix products: default
#> BLAS:   /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRblas.0.dylib
#> LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib
#> 
#> locale:
#> [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
#> 
#> attached base packages:
#> [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     
#> 
#> other attached packages:
#> [1] streamR_0.4.5   ndjson_0.7.0    rjson_0.2.20    RCurl_1.95-4.12
#> [5] bitops_1.0-6   
#> 
#> loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#>  [1] Rcpp_1.0.2        knitr_1.25        magrittr_1.5     
#>  [4] tidyselect_0.2.5  R6_2.4.0          rlang_0.4.0      
#>  [7] ROAuth_0.9.6      stringr_1.4.0     highr_0.8        
#> [10] dplyr_0.8.3       tools_3.6.1       data.table_1.12.2
#> [13] xfun_0.9          htmltools_0.3.6   yaml_2.2.0       
#> [16] digest_0.6.21     assertthat_0.2.1  tibble_2.1.3     
#> [19] crayon_1.3.4      dtplyr_0.0.3      purrr_0.3.2      
#> [22] glue_1.3.1        evaluate_0.14     rmarkdown_1.15   
#> [25] stringi_1.4.3     compiler_3.6.1    pillar_1.4.2     
#> [28] pkgconfig_2.0.3
```

<sup>Created on 2019-10-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: From the sessionInfo() command I become aware that I didn't had the newest version of R, I updated it and then it all worked! Thanks a lot!